# Rendered HTML in email body

Tags: python, django

I want to mail a simple HTML file containing some data. I want the user to receive rendered HTML. I've tried this solution:

```
b = render_to_string('mail_body.html',{'name':request.POST['name']})
send_mail(email_subject,b,'sender@gmail.com', ['receiver@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False)
```

but I don't get rendered HTML in the mail body and the user can see all of the HTML tags!

Alternatively, when I use the following code I just get the path of my HTML file in the mail body:

```
params = {}
params['name'] = request.POST['name']
context = Context(params)
t = Template('mail_body.html')
send_mail(email_subject,t.render(context), 'sender@gmail.com',
    ['receiver@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: I was thinking, the styles are all inlined in .html

Comment: I recommend using http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473810-send-an-html-email-with-embedded-image-and-plain-t/ - this handles formatting for html/attachments/images etc... and offers a way to also send plain text - I've used it in several projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
body = render_to_string(template_name, locals(),
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, mail_sender, [contact_request.email], headers={'Reply-To': 'do_not_reply@whatever.com'})
email.content_subtype='html'
email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

Hope this leads into the right direction. Just note that there are a lot of variables in here which come from my own programming.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to tell the users mail client that you are sending them an HTML email, otherwise it will just show the HTML as if it were text.

The setting is called a MIME type, you can read more about how to set this (and send HTML emails in python) in the [python user guides](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#id4).